# lateinit property str has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm currently learning Dagger Hilt but I've come across an issue:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property str has not been initialized
        at com.example.kotlin20test.MainActivity.getStr(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.example.kotlin20test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
```

Here are my files:

**MainActivity**:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    @Inject lateinit var str: String
    @Inject private lateinit var api: JsonPlaceholderApi

    lateinit var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
       if(str != null){
           println(str)
       }


    }}
```

**MyModule**:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyModule{

 @Provides
    fun provideString(): String{
        return "Look, It's a string"
    }


}
```

And I've also tried Retrofit with hilt and it gave me the same error, and I've read many **Stack overflow** regarding this issue and tried the answers but nothing seems to work.

Edit: I forgot to add the app class and the manifest so here it is:

**MyApp**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application(){
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kotlin20test">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kotlin20Test">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to check if a Kotlin lateinit var has been initialized is with the
KProperty value isInitialized, turning this:

```
if(str != null){
    println(str)
}
```

into this:

```
if(::str.isInitialized){
    println(str)
}
```

Edit: As another user pointed out I erroneously included a ! originally.

Answer (score 0):

While you have not yet initialized your variable, it will give UninitializedPropertyAccessException when you try to get it, even for `str != null`

as @VelocityCubeR said, kotlin have other method to check if a property has been initialized, buе he was wrong with `!`

you must change `str != null` to `::str.isInitialized`

Dagger Hilt not relevant to this exception, this is basic kotlin syntax, [read more here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables)

Comment: I did that and the app works fine, but still the problem remains that nothing is logged and when I remove the check it still gives me the same error, by the way there is an app class annotated with @HiltAndroidApp, and I added that class to the manifest

Answer (score -1):

hey you forget the `@Singleton` annotation

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyModule{

@Singleton <------ include this
@Provides
fun provideString(): String{
    return "Look, It's a string"
 }
 }
```

Comment: ok i created a new project with the same exact code but without

        lateinit var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
        and
        mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 

and it worked. please try this if u havnt , thanks

Comment: I used delegation and the plain old findViewById, still it prints the same error. To reiterate again, I just want the String to printed to the console using Hilt, and Sorry if I'm bothering you bro.

Comment: haha glad to help bro, its clearly something to do with the way ur ui is binded, ur hilt implementation is correct, if i get any further answers i will comment here.